# CSS bug on blockquotes in Review Suggested Edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, design

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17605861

---

While doing my duty 
by reviewing suggested edits I came across this:

[image: Bad blockquotes padding]

I first thought the edit added an unwanted newline, so I clicked on Improve edit to see that:

[image: Good blockquotes padding]

As you can see blockquotes in Review Suggested Edits page add too much padding at the end of blockquotes and makes feels there is a useless empty line, but it's not.

Comment: Looks like it's missing `blockquote *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}`. That's what normal posts have to keep this from happening.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I tried it with firebug before posting - it did not work - but maybe I've messed something, I don't care too much about css, so I ended it here :)

Comment: You are correct. I should have tried it myself. The problem is that there is an empty `<span class="diff-add"></span>` right after the paragraph, so the `:last-child` ends up targeting that instead. The `.diff-add` is used to highlight changes, so it probably shouldn't be there (another is in the paragraph already). I'm guessing that their algorithm is highlighting blank lines that are added.